Where and how to add an export button in an area with many buttons and fields
I have the following area on a website for displaying products in a CRM, and need to add a button that will export them to a CSV, however I am having trouble making it look good as there are already multiple buttons in this area

I tried moving the export to the left side so the right side isn't crowded with buttons but I think this still looks bad

I've also tried switching to a more subtle looking button, I think this looks weird here but also not sure if I would want to move on the right side with the other buttons


Did you try placing your subtle looking Export Products button on the right AND moving the paginator to the left?
My thinking here is that navigating through the pages of products should be connected with the Showing 1 to 25 of 150 results text. Those 2 pieces relate to each other.
Could you also move search to the top-right and have both Export and New Product as primary and secondary buttons on the bottom-right?
Could you also post a full page with the product table and list so we can see how the whole page appears?

With the end user experience better place is right side, so then keep that in right side. for looks improve try to think different way (ex:add icon)

can you explain why?
